# Split of path in an order

Tags: path

I need to split a path in this way

```
/sandy/user1/user2/abc.txt
/sandy/user1/user2
/sandy/user1
/sandy
/
```

Comment: unix philosophy?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are asking but here's a shot in the dark:

```
path=/sandy/user1/user2/abc.txt
while [ "$path" ]; do
    printf '%s ' "$path"
    path=${path%/*} # remove trailing path component
done
echo /
```

Output: `/sandy/user1/user2/abc.txt /sandy/user1/user2 /sandy/user1 /sandy /`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is any path or if it is the given path

In Linux, it works this way

If the file path is in $FILE_PATH

echo $FILE_PATH | rev | sed 's/[^/]*///' | rev
will give
/sandy/user1/user2

echo $FILE_PATH | rev | cut -d '/' -f 3,4 | rev
will give
sandy/user1

You have to choose accordingly and modify as per your data and needs.